# How to fix "Intermediate Stream methods should not be left unused" on Sonarqube

Tags: java, sonarqube

I found this bug on Sonarqube:

```java
private String getMacAdressByPorts(Set<Integer> ports) {
    ports.stream().sorted(); // sonar list show "Refactor the code so this stream pipeline is used"
    return ports.toString();
} //getMacAdressByPorts
```

I have been searching for a long time on the Internet, but it was no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: What is that code supposed to do? Right now it does nothing but create some `Stream` objects—it doesn't even execute the stream.

Comment: Hi @Slaw  thanks for your reminder, I add the complete code. We can use getMacAdressByPorts function to get String.

Comment: Your stream code still does nothing. A stream is only executed if you invoke a _terminal operation_, of which `sorted()` is not. Even if you invoked a terminal operation here it's not like it will sort the `Set` in place. The set only serves as the _source_ of the stream. If you want to return a single `String` from the sorted stream then look into [`Collectors.joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining(java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence,java.lang.CharSequence)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the problem used the code below.

```
private String getMacAdressByPorts(Set<Integer> ports) {
        return ports.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()).toString();
```

Comment: Don't hesitate to mention in your answer why it didn't work. That way your accepted answer may be more useful to others coming to this question !

Answer (score 5):

The `sorted()` method has no effect on the `Set` you pass in; actually, it's a non-terminal operation, so it isn't even executed. If you want to sort your ports, you need something like

```
return ports.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
```

EDIT:
as @Slaw correctly points out, to get the same format you had before (ie `[item1, item2, item3]`, you also need to add the square brackets to the joining collector, ie `Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]")`. I left those out for simplicity.

Comment: Note to get the same output as typical implementations of `Set` the OP should use `Collectors.joining(", ", "[", "]")`.

Comment: It work but show the other error message below. 
 "(argument mismatch; java.util.stream.Collector<java.lang.CharSequence,capture#1 of ?,java.lang.String> cannot be converted to java.util.stream.Collector<? super java.lang.Integer,A,R>))"

Comment: @Batterie Put a `.map(Integer::toString)` after `.sorted()`?

Comment: Error message appeared and showed " non-static method toString() cannot be referenced from a static context " .
I solve the problem and thanks for your answer sincerely. You gave me a lot of inspiration to solve it.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Sonar Source documentation](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-3959) about this warning (emphasis of mine):

> Stream operations are divided into **intermediate** and **terminal** operations, and are combined to form stream pipelines. After the terminal operation is performed, the stream pipeline is considered consumed, and cannot be used again. Such a reuse will yield unexpected results.

[Official JavaDoc for stream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html) gives more details on `sorted()` (emphasis of mine):

> Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream, sorted according to natural order. If the elements of this stream are not Comparable, a java.lang.ClassCastException may be thrown when the terminal operation is executed. [...] **This is a stateful intermediate operation.**

This implies that only using `sorted()` will yield no result. From the [Oracle Stream package documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#StreamOps) (still emphasis of mine):

> Stream operations are divided into intermediate and terminal operations, and are combined to form stream pipelines. A stream pipeline consists of a source (such as a Collection, an array, a generator function, or an I/O channel); followed by zero or more **intermediate** operations such as Stream.filter or Stream.map; and a **terminal** operation such as Stream.forEach or Stream.reduce.

> Intermediate operations return a new stream. **They are always lazy**; executing an intermediate operation such as filter() **does not actually perform any filtering**, but instead creates a new stream that, when traversed, contains the elements of the initial stream that match the given predicate. Traversal of the pipeline source does not begin until the terminal operation of the pipeline is executed.

`sorted()` returns another `stream()`, and not a sorted list. To solve your Sonar issue (and maybe your code issue, in that manner), you have to call a terminal operation in order to run all the intermediate operations. You can find a list (non-exhausive, I think) of terminal operations [on CodeJava for instance](https://www.codejava.net/java-core/collections/java-8-stream-terminal-operations-examples).

---

In your case, the solution might look like:

```
private String getMacAdressByPorts(Set<Integer> ports) {
    /* Ports > Stream > Sort (intermediate operation) > 
    / Collector (final operation) > List > String
    / Note that you need to import the static method toList()
    / from the Collector API, otherwise it won't compile
    */

    return ports.stream().sorted().collect(toList()).toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank for your response and your response make me more clearly for my question. I'm trying to use collect() to correct my problem but I encounter the error message "cannot be converted to java.util.stream.Collector"

Comment: Yeah, `collect()` returns a `Collector` as indicated. You can import the static method `toList` from the Collector API (`import java.util.stream.Collectors.toList`), then use something among the lines of `List<Integer> sortedList = ports.stream().sorted().collect(toList());`.

Comment: thanks for your commitment, I finally solved the problem by your method and added some  code to make it complete.

Comment: You're welcome ! Glad it has been helpful.